# For loop within a for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop

For some reason my outer for loop does not seem to be doing anything, I have checked all the paranthesis and everything looks ok but it is still not looping.
With this program I want to sum 50 random numbers (the numbers can either be 1 or -1...it's for a computational physics problem) and print the magnitude, which the program does. BUT I want to go further and do this 10 times, and calculate the average magnitude.
I know what I need to do I'm just having a problem with this loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h> //Neeed this to seed the random generator with time, or else it      will always generate the same numbers.

//This is a program to calculate the magnitude of the displacement of a particle after    random collisions.
#define RAND_MAX 1
int main()
{   
    //using ints because the particle can only move one unit on x-axis at a time.
    int i, x, displacement, sum = 0, avg;
    int total_disp=0, mag_disp;
    srand(time(NULL));


    //Each collision causes the particle to advance or retreat by one unit on the x axis.

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {   
        for (i=0; i<50; i++)    //for 50 collisions
        {

            x = rand() % 2;  //generates random numbers between 0 and 1.
            if (x==0)   //if x is 0 then it was a displacement in the minus x direction
            {
                displacement = -1;
            }
            else {  //if x is 1 it is a displacement in the minus x direction
                displacement = 1;
            }
            printf("the disp is : %d\n", displacement);
            total_disp = total_disp + displacement;     //sum the displacements

        }

        if (total_disp < 0) {
            mag_disp = total_disp * -1;
        }

        else{ mag_disp = total_disp; }

        printf("The total displacement is: %d\n", mag_disp);
        sum = sum + mag_disp;   //sum of the displacement magnitudes, there should be ten of them in this case
        avg = sum / i; //average displacement is the sum of all the magnitudes divded by the number of times this is performed.
        printf("The average displacement for i = %d particles is: %d", i, avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't redefine `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: You should set `total_disp` to 0 inside the outer loop, before the start of the inner loop. Both this error and the one about using the same variable for both loops would be avoided if you separated the different things you're doing into different functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the same iteration variable in both loops.

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (i=0; i<50; i++)
```

increments `i` to `50` in the first iteration of the outer loop.

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (j=0; j<50; j++)
```

will work.

Answer (score 5):

You're using the same variable `i` for both loops. You should use different variables.

```
...
for(j=0; j<10; j++)
{    
   for (i=0; i<50; i++)    //for 50 collisions
   {
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use different loop variables for the inner and outer loops.

When the first iteration of the inner loop is done `i == 50`, so the outer loop is also done.

Comment: no, last time the loop is entered, i==49. i is then incremented by one and the loop test `i<50` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<50; j++)
    { ... }
}
```

And change your variables accordingly.

Comment: Pointless fact: it would have worked to name both variables 'i' if you did like this and declared the iterator inside the for loop. Whenever 'i' was accessed from the inner-most loop, it would have referred to the inner-most 'i'. But... don't name them the same thing, it just makes the code hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Dennis is right.

in ANSI C, i and j must be declared in the begining of the function :

```
int main()
{
int i,j;

...//instructions

 for( i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    for( j=0; j<50; j++)
    { ... }
}
```